# How do you query for items that are in another set of items in LINQ?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I have two data sources and want to iterate through the first, filtering on the existence of a field in the other data source, as shown in the pseudocode below:

```
DataContext1 db1 = new DataContext1();
DataContext2 db2 = new DataContext2();

foreach(Address address in db1.Addresses.Where(l => l.LocationCode in db2.AddressList.Select(c => c.LocationCode)))
{
    // perform operations
}
```

What would the proper syntax be to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Add `AsEnumerable()` after the select in db2

```
foreach(Address address in db1.Addresses.Where(l => 
   db2.AddressList.Select(c => c.LocationCode).AsEnumerable().Contains(l.LocationCode)))
{
    // perform operations
}
```

Comment: thanks, i tried you suggestion - the compiler is complaining that it can't implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool' at `l.LocationCode`...there are a few other errors as well.